# Error for language "French (France)", but not for "French (Canada)"

Tags: simulator

I have a problem with the simulator "Trivia Game Multiple Choice", when I use language "French (Canada)", simulator is OK, I can play, but when I use French (France), the simulation does not work anymore, I can't.

Image :

Image : [French (Canada)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7G64.png), and image
[French (France)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EosYV.png)

Sorry, I do not speak English very well
Thank you for your help

Comment: What is "the simulator"? There are literally thousands of simulators. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Thx, for "Trivia Game Multiple Choice"

Comment: No, I'm not asking what your program is called. What system is the simulator for? iOS simulator? Android simulator? DOS simulator? Commodore 64 simulator? Flight simulator?

Comment: Android  simulator, sorry